# Twitter Entities : weird twitter/tweepy behaviour

Tags: python, twitter, dictionary, tweepy

Normally when I use twitter streaming api, I can directly access hashtags directly from:

tweet -> entities -> hashtags

[image]

When searching for tweets talking about a keyword/hashtag with tweepy, it downloads a `<class 'tweepy.models.Status'>` .

```
c = tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=hashtag,include_entities=True,rpp=100).items(limit)

while (True) :
    try:
        __tweet = next(c)
        _tweet = jsonpickle.encode(__tweet)
        tweet = json.loads(_tweet)
         ....
```

When I search for entities/hashtags, I find the first one (wich I look for) under author.

tweet -> author -> entities -> hashtags

Which is strange.

[image]

The "hashtags" that is located under

tweet -> entities -> hashtags

looks like this :

```
(u'entities', {
    u'symbols': {u'py/id': 17},
    u'user_mentions': {u'py/id': 20},
    u'hashtags': {u'py/id': 13},
    u'urls': {u'py/id': 18},
    }),
```

When I try to extract hashtags from

tweet -> author -> entities -> hashtags -> text

within a loop:

```
_hashtags = []
__hashtags = []
try:
    _hashtags = tweet['author']['entities']['hashtags'] 
    for element in _hashtags:
        __hashtags.append(element['text'])
    hashtags = ' '.join(e for e in __hashtags)
except KeyError, e:
    hashtags = None
    logger.warning (e.__doc__)
    logger.warning (e.message)
    exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
    logger.warning (exc_type)
    logger.warning (fname) 
    logger.warning (exc_tb.tb_lineno)
```

The result: hashtags is a null string ..

While working with :

tweet -> entities -> hashtags -> text

```
_hashtags = []
__hashtags = []
try:
    _hashtags = tweet['entities']['hashtags']   
    for element in _hashtags:
        __hashtags.append(element['text'])
    hashtags = ' '.join(e for e in __hashtags)
except KeyError, e:
    hashtags = None
    logger.warning (e.__doc__)
    logger.warning (e.message)
    exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
    logger.warning (exc_type)
    logger.warning (fname) 
    logger.warning (exc_tb.tb_lineno)
```

generate this error :

```
    __hashtags.append(element['text'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I remember that I was working with the last one last time and it was working .. I don't know why it stopped giving good results !

Twitter says that entities is accessible directly within the tweet response : https://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/tweets

This is the `pprint(tweet)`'s output:

```
[
    (u'contributors', None),
    (u'truncated', False),
    (u'retweeted', False),
    (u'in_reply_to_status_id', None),
    (u'id', 487988233016340482L),
    (u'favorite_count', 0),
    (u'py/object', u'tweepy.models.Status'),
    (u'_api', {
        u'py/object': u'tweepy.api.API',
        u'wait_on_rate_limit': False,
        u'cache': None,
        u'secure': True,
        u'retry_errors': None,
        u'search_host': u'search.twitter.com',
        u'parser': {u'py/object': u'tweepy.parsers.ModelParser',
                    u'json_lib': {u'py/repr': u'json/json'},
                    u'model_factory': {u'py/type': u'tweepy.models.ModelFactory'
                    }},
        u'auth': {
            u'py/object': u'tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler',
            u'username': None,
            u'_consumer': {u'py/object': u'tweepy.oauth.OAuthConsumer',
                           u'secret': u'xxxxxx'
                           , u'key': u'xxxxxx'},
            u'secure': True,
            u'_sigmethod': {u'py/object': u'tweepy.oauth.OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1'
                            },
            u'access_token': {u'py/object': u'tweepy.oauth.OAuthToken',
                              u'secret':xxxxx'
                              ,
                              u'key': u'xxxxxx'
                              },
            u'callback': None,
            u'request_token': None,
            },
        u'cached_result': False,
        u'search_root': u'',
        u'retry_count': 0,
        u'host': u'api.twitter.com',
        u'timeout': 60,
        u'api_root': u'/1.1',
        u'retry_delay': 0,
        u'wait_on_rate_limit_notify': False,
        u'last_response': {
            u'py/object': u'httplib.HTTPResponse',
            u'fp': None,
            u'will_close': False,
            u'chunk_left': u'UNKNOWN',
            u'length': 0,
            u'strict': 0,
            u'reason': u'OK',
            u'version': 11,
            u'status': 200,
            u'debuglevel': 0,
            u'msg': {
                u'py/object': u'httplib.HTTPMessage',
                u'fp': None,
                u'startofbody': None,
                u'startofheaders': None,
                u'headers': [
                    u'cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0\r\n'
                        ,
                    u'content-length: 64932\r\n',
                    u'content-type: application/json;charset=utf-8\r\n'
                        ,
                    u'date: Sat, 12 Jul 2014 15:59:00 GMT\r\n',
                    u'expires: Tue, 31 Mar 1981 05:00:00 GMT\r\n',
                    u'last-modified: Sat, 12 Jul 2014 15:59:00 GMT\r\n'
                        ,
                    u'pragma: no-cache\r\n',
                    u'server: tfe\r\n',
                    u'set-cookie: lang=en\r\n',
                    u'set-cookie: guest_id=v1%3A140518074073079236; Domain=.twitter.com; Path=/; Expires=Mon, 11-Jul-2016 15:59:00 UTC\r\n'
                        ,
                    u'status: 200 OK\r\n',
                    u'strict-transport-security: max-age=631138519\r\n'
                        ,
                    u'x-access-level: read-write-directmessages\r\n',
                    u'x-content-type-options: nosniff\r\n',
                    u'x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN\r\n',
                    u'x-rate-limit-limit: 180\r\n',
                    u'x-rate-limit-remaining: 177\r\n',
                    u'x-rate-limit-reset: 1405181566\r\n',
                    u'x-transaction: 9bf3522d6235b71a\r\n',
                    u'x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block\r\n',
                    ],
                u'plisttext': u';charset=utf-8',
                u'maintype': u'application',
                u'subtype': u'json',
                u'status': u'',
                u'typeheader': u'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                u'encodingheader': None,
                u'seekable': 0,
                u'dict': {
                    u'status': u'200 OK',
                    u'x-rate-limit-remaining': u'177',
                    u'content-length': u'64932',
                    u'expires': u'Tue, 31 Mar 1981 05:00:00 GMT',
                    u'x-transaction': u'9bf3522d6235b71a',
                    u'x-content-type-options': u'nosniff',
                    u'set-cookie': u'lang=en, guest_id=v1%3A140518074073079236; Domain=.twitter.com; Path=/; Expires=Mon, 11-Jul-2016 15:59:00 UTC'
                        ,
                    u'strict-transport-security': u'max-age=631138519',
                    u'x-access-level': u'read-write-directmessages',
                    u'server': u'tfe',
                    u'last-modified': u'Sat, 12 Jul 2014 15:59:00 GMT',
                    u'x-xss-protection': u'1; mode=block',
                    u'x-rate-limit-reset': u'1405181566',
                    u'pragma': u'no-cache',
                    u'cache-control': u'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0'
                        ,
                    u'date': u'Sat, 12 Jul 2014 15:59:00 GMT',
                    u'x-rate-limit-limit': u'180',
                    u'x-frame-options': u'SAMEORIGIN',
                    u'content-type': u'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                    },
                u'unixfrom': u'',
                u'type': u'application/json',
                u'plist': [u'charset=utf-8'],
                },
            u'chunked': 0,
            u'_method': u'GET',
            },
        u'compression': False,
        }),
    (u'author', {
        u'follow_request_sent': False,
        u'profile_use_background_image': True,
        u'profile_sidebar_fill_color': u'171106',
        u'id': 14076230,
        u'py/object': u'tweepy.models.User',
        u'_api': {u'py/id': 1},
        u'verified': False,
        u'profile_text_color': u'8A7302',
        u'profile_image_url_https': u'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000592595006/b0dce59ad7eb453c70b32cb1cf79657e_normal.jpeg'
            ,
        u'_json': {
            u'follow_request_sent': False,
            u'profile_use_background_image': True,
            u'id': 14076230,
            u'verified': False,
            u'profile_text_color': u'8A7302',
            u'profile_image_url_https': u'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000592595006/b0dce59ad7eb453c70b32cb1cf79657e_normal.jpeg'
                ,
            u'profile_sidebar_fill_color': u'171106',
            u'is_translator': False,
            u'geo_enabled': True,
            u'entities': {u'url': {u'urls': {u'py/id': 32}},
                          u'description': {u'urls': {u'py/id': 31}}},
            u'followers_count': 974,
            u'profile_sidebar_border_color': u'FFFFFF',
            u'id_str': u'14076230',
            u'default_profile_image': False,
            u'location': u'Adelaide, Australia',
            u'is_translation_enabled': False,
            u'utc_offset': 34200,
            u'statuses_count': 6856,
            u'description': u'eBusiness Advisor, online communications advocate and student. Creating, sharing and curating media. also e-learning, websites and business use of online tools'
                ,
            u'friends_count': 786,
            u'profile_link_color': u'473623',
            u'profile_image_url': u'http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000592595006/b0dce59ad7eb453c70b32cb1cf79657e_normal.jpeg'
                ,
            u'notifications': False,
            u'profile_background_image_url_https': u'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/378800000167684076/EcbKsmde.jpeg'
                ,
            u'profile_background_color': u'0F0A02',
            u'profile_banner_url': u'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/14076230/1381709041'
                ,
            u'profile_background_image_url': u'http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/378800000167684076/EcbKsmde.jpeg'
                ,
            u'name': u'Rhys Moult',
            u'lang': u'en',
            u'profile_background_tile': True,
            u'favourites_count': 115,
            u'screen_name': u'rhysatwork',
            u'url': u'http://t.co/hUmuflFD3V',
            u'created_at': u'Tue Mar 04 04:03:39 +0000 2008',
            u'contributors_enabled': False,
            u'time_zone': u'Adelaide',
            u'protected': False,
            u'default_profile': False,
            u'following': False,
            u'listed_count': 71,
            },
        u'is_translator': False,
        u'geo_enabled': True,
        u'entities': {u'url': {u'urls': {u'py/id': 32}},
                      u'description': {u'urls': {u'py/id': 31}}},
        u'followers_count': 974,
        u'profile_sidebar_border_color': u'FFFFFF',
        u'location': u'Adelaide, Australia',
        u'default_profile_image': False,
        u'id_str': u'14076230',
        u'is_translation_enabled': False,
        u'utc_offset': 34200,
        u'statuses_count': 6856,
        u'description': u'eBusiness Advisor, online communications advocate and student. Creating, sharing and curating media. also e-learning, websites and business use of online tools'
            ,
        u'friends_count': 786,
        u'profile_link_color': u'473623',
        u'profile_image_url': u'http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000592595006/b0dce59ad7eb453c70b32cb1cf79657e_normal.jpeg'
            ,
        u'notifications': False,
        u'profile_background_image_url_https': u'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/378800000167684076/EcbKsmde.jpeg'
            ,
        u'profile_background_color': u'0F0A02',
        u'profile_banner_url': u'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/14076230/1381709041'
            ,
        u'profile_background_image_url': u'http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/378800000167684076/EcbKsmde.jpeg'
            ,
        u'name': u'Rhys Moult',
        u'lang': u'en',
        u'profile_background_tile': True,
        u'favourites_count': 115,
        u'screen_name': u'rhysatwork',
        u'url': u'http://t.co/hUmuflFD3V',
        u'created_at': {u'py/object': u'datetime.datetime',
                        u'__reduce__': [{u'py/type': u'datetime.datetime'
                        }, [u'B9gDBAQDJwAAAA==']]},
        u'contributors_enabled': False,
        u'time_zone': u'Adelaide',
        u'protected': False,
        u'default_profile': False,
        u'following': False,
        u'listed_count': 71,
        }),
    (u'_json', {
        u'contributors': None,
        u'truncated': False,
        u'text': u'Our #govhack app FB page for @unleashedADL https://t.co/3VyvgUurCu #opendata @WhatGrowsHere #natureninjas'
            ,
        u'in_reply_to_status_id': None,
        u'in_reply_to_user_id': None,
        u'id': 487988233016340482L,
        u'favorite_count': 0,
        u'source': u'<a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone</a>'
            ,
        u'retweeted': False,
        u'coordinates': {u'type': u'Point',
                         u'coordinates': [138.48741864, -34.84890577]},
        u'entities': {
            u'symbols': [],
            u'user_mentions': [{
                u'indices': [29, 42],
                u'id_str': u'1287906530',
                u'screen_name': u'unleashedADL',
                u'name': u'Unleashed Adelaide',
                u'id': 1287906530,
                }, {
                u'indices': [77, 91],
                u'id_str': u'2620349570',
                u'screen_name': u'WhatGrowsHere',
                u'name': u'What grows here',
                u'id': 2620349570L,
                }],
            u'hashtags': [{u'indices': [4, 12], u'text': u'govhack'},
                          {u'indices': [67, 76], u'text': u'opendata'},
                          {u'indices': [92, 105],
                          u'text': u'natureninjas'}],
            u'urls': [{
                u'indices': [43, 66],
                u'url': u'https://t.co/3VyvgUurCu',
                u'expanded_url': u'https://m.facebook.com/WhatGrowsHere'
                    ,
                u'display_url': u'm.facebook.com/WhatGrowsHere',
                }],
            },
        u'in_reply_to_screen_name': None,
        u'id_str': u'487988233016340482',
        u'retweet_count': 0,
        u'metadata': {u'iso_language_code': u'en',
                      u'result_type': u'recent'},
        u'favorited': False,
        u'user': {
            u'follow_request_sent': False,
            u'profile_use_background_image': True,
            u'id': 14076230,
            u'verified': False,
            u'profile_text_color': u'8A7302',
            u'profile_image_url_https': u'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000592595006/b0dce59ad7eb453c70b32cb1cf79657e_normal.jpeg'
                ,
            u'profile_sidebar_fill_color': u'171106',
            u'is_translator': False,
            u'geo_enabled': True,
            u'entities': {u'url': {u'urls': [{
                u'indices': [0, 22],
                u'url': u'http://t.co/hUmuflFD3V',
                u'expanded_url': u'http://rhysatwork.com',
                u'display_url': u'rhysatwork.com',
                }]}, u'description': {u'urls': []}},
            u'followers_count': 974,
            u'profile_sidebar_border_color': u'FFFFFF',
            u'id_str': u'14076230',
            u'default_profile_image': False,
            u'location': u'Adelaide, Australia',
            u'is_translation_enabled': False,
            u'utc_offset': 34200,
            u'statuses_count': 6856,
            u'description': u'eBusiness Advisor, online communications advocate and student. Creating, sharing and curating media. also e-learning, websites and business use of online tools'
                ,
            u'friends_count': 786,
            u'profile_link_color': u'473623',
            u'profile_image_url': u'http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000592595006/b0dce59ad7eb453c70b32cb1cf79657e_normal.jpeg'
                ,
            u'notifications': False,
            u'profile_background_image_url_https': u'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/378800000167684076/EcbKsmde.jpeg'
                ,
            u'profile_background_color': u'0F0A02',
            u'profile_banner_url': u'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/14076230/1381709041'
                ,
            u'profile_background_image_url': u'http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/378800000167684076/EcbKsmde.jpeg'
                ,
            u'name': u'Rhys Moult',
            u'lang': u'en',
            u'profile_background_tile': True,
            u'favourites_count': 115,
            u'screen_name': u'rhysatwork',
            u'url': u'http://t.co/hUmuflFD3V',
            u'created_at': u'Tue Mar 04 04:03:39 +0000 2008',
            u'contributors_enabled': False,
            u'time_zone': u'Adelaide',
            u'protected': False,
            u'default_profile': False,
            u'following': False,
            u'listed_count': 71,
            },
        u'geo': {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [-34.84890577,
                 138.48741864]},
        u'in_reply_to_user_id_str': None,
        u'possibly_sensitive': False,
        u'lang': u'en',
        u'created_at': u'Sat Jul 12 15:53:55 +0000 2014',
        u'in_reply_to_status_id_str': None,
        u'place': {
            u'full_name': u'Adelaide',
            u'url': u'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/01e8a1a140ccdc5c.json'
                ,
            u'country': u'Australia',
            u'place_type': u'city',
            u'bounding_box': {u'type': u'Polygon',
                              u'coordinates': [[[138.44212992,
                              -35.348970061], [138.780189824,
                              -35.348970061], [138.780189824,
                              -34.652564053], [138.44212992,
                              -34.652564053]]]},
            u'contained_within': [],
            u'country_code': u'AU',
            u'attributes': {},
            u'id': u'01e8a1a140ccdc5c',
            u'name': u'Adelaide',
            },
        }),
    (u'coordinates', {u'type': u'Point',
     u'coordinates': {u'py/id': 12}}),
    (u'in_reply_to_user_id_str', None),
    (u'entities', {
        u'symbols': {u'py/id': 17},
        u'user_mentions': {u'py/id': 20},
        u'hashtags': {u'py/id': 13},
        u'urls': {u'py/id': 18},
        }),
    (u'in_reply_to_screen_name', None),
    (u'in_reply_to_user_id', None),
    (u'text',
     u'Our #govhack app FB page for @unleashedADL https://t.co/3VyvgUurCu #opendata @WhatGrowsHere #natureninjas'
     ),
    (u'retweet_count', 0),
    (u'metadata', {u'iso_language_code': u'en',
     u'result_type': u'recent'}),
    (u'favorited', False),
    (u'source_url', u'http://twitter.com/download/iphone'),
    (u'user', {u'py/id': 34}),
    (u'geo', {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': {u'py/id': 23}}),
    (u'id_str', u'487988233016340482'),
    (u'possibly_sensitive', False),
    (u'lang', u'en'),
    (u'created_at', {u'py/object': u'datetime.datetime',
     u'__reduce__': [{u'py/type': u'datetime.datetime'},
     [u'B94HDA81NwAAAA==']]}),
    (u'in_reply_to_status_id_str', None),
    (u'place', {
        u'py/object': u'tweepy.models.Place',
        u'_api': {u'py/id': 1},
        u'country_code': u'AU',
        u'url': u'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/01e8a1a140ccdc5c.json'
            ,
        u'country': u'Australia',
        u'place_type': u'city',
        u'bounding_box': {
            u'py/object': u'tweepy.models.BoundingBox',
            u'_api': {u'py/id': 1},
            u'type': u'Polygon',
            u'coordinates': {u'py/id': 24},
            },
        u'contained_within': {
            u'py/object': u'tweepy.models.ResultSet',
            u'_since_id': None,
            u'_max_id': None,
            u'py/seq': [],
            },
        u'full_name': u'Adelaide',
        u'attributes': {},
        u'id': u'01e8a1a140ccdc5c',
        u'name': u'Adelaide',
        }),
    (u'source', u'Twitter for iPhone'),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

While working with "tweet -> author -> entities -> hashtags -> text", in the code:

```
try:
    _hashtags = tweet['author']['entities']['hashtags'] 
    for element in _hashtags:
        __hashtags.append(element['text'])
    hashtags = ' '.join(e for e in __hashtags)
```

Where does your __hashtags declared ? emptied ? Why "_" ? "__" ? That's not readable nor debuggable, I would prefer:

```
try:
    hashtags_texts = []
    hashtags = tweet['author']['entities']['hashtags'] 
    for hashtag in hashtags:
        hashtags_texts.append(hashtag['text'])
    hashtags = ' '.join(hashtags_text)
```

or

```
try:
    hashtags = ' '.join(hashtag['text'] for hashtag in
                        tweet['author']['entities']['hashtags'])
```

Then what are you doing with your hashtags ? Are your sure tweet['author']['entities']['hashtags'] actually contains data ? Are you sure hashtags is an empty string ?

Comment: I will add the decalaration and the pprint of tweet in my message.

Answer (score 0):

When using jsonpickle in my code :

```
    __tweet = next(c)
    _tweet = jsonpickle.encode(__tweet)
    tweet = json.loads(_tweet)
```

I discovered that the structure changed .
So `hashtags` can be found under `_json->entities->..etc`